# Monitor network activity on google-earth plugin installer download

Tags: windows, networking, google-earth-plugin

I'm creating an application using the Google Earth plugin (http://www.google.com/intl/en/earth/explore/products/plugin.html).  Typically, to install the plugin a user would go to that site, click the download button, and a small executable would download.  They'd then run that executable, which is a Google installation package I guess, and that installation package would download the actual plugin and install it.

I have run into an issue where some users are unable to do all this because they are behind a corporate firewall or use a proxy and they are somehow blocked from using the Google installation package.  I have heard that you can monitor your network activity while the Google installer is running and you can see the location that Google is downloading the plugin from, thus getting the direct link to the full download.  I'm not sure how to do this though, can anyone help?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Once installed and started, it will act as a proxy and list all http requests.